How to print your word document with background color on mac?
I would like to print a word document with a background color on a macbook. The problem is that when I want to print the document it remains white. Here an example:

And here the result when printing:

I was only able to find solution for this on windows and not on a MacBook (apple). For example here is a tutorial but it for windows. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this on a Mac?
I'm using Microsoft Word for Mac with this version 16.84 (24041420).

Have you set these options?

Word by default doesn't print background colors. If you really want to print the background color, you can activate it in the Options. On Windows this is under File > Options > Display > Print Background Colors and Images. On Mac it will also be somewhere in the options but I think there they are called "preferences".
However, please keep a few important things in mind:

Your printer will use a high amount of ink or toner emptying your cartridges very quickly.
Your paper might not be able to absorb that much ink well and it might start getting "wavy".
Most home printers cannot print borderless, so you might have a thin white border around your page.

In general, if you want to have a colored background, it would be best to buy paper that is already colored, and print on that colored paper. That would avoid the previously mentioned issues.
